# Recharts Piechart - conditionally displaying label on each section in pie

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I need to make Pie chart with three section using React Recharts.

I have two questions:

1. On mouse hover , I want to show the text with percentage in tooltip. how to get percentage value in tooltip?
2. On size change, if some section in pie is too small then I need to hide the label; how to achieve this?

My sample code

```
const {PieChart, Pie, Sector} = Recharts;
const data = [{name: 'Group A', value: 400}, {name: 'Group B', value: 300},
                  {name: 'Group C', value: 300}, {name: 'Group D', value: 200}]; 
function renderCustomToolTip({active, label, payload}) {
  return(
  <div>
    <p> payload[0].label </p>
// need to add percentage value in tooltip
  </div>
);
}
class PieChart extends from React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeIndex: 0
        }
    }
    onPieEnter(data, index) {
        this.setState({
          activeIndex: index,
        });
      }
      render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <PieChart width={800} height={400}>
                <Pie 
                    activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
                    activeShape={renderActiveShape} 
                    data={data} 
                    cx={300} 
                    cy={200} 
                    innerRadius={60}
                    outerRadius={80} 
                    fill="#8884d8"
                    labelLine={false}
                    label={renderCustomizedLabel}
                    onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}
                />
          {
            data.map((entry, index) => <Cell fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]}/>)
          }
          <ToolTip content={renderCustomToolTip} />
          </PieChart>
         </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Using activeShape, able to get each section percentage value, but I need to display percentage in tooltip.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do for percentage:

```
renderCustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
    if (active) {
        return (
            <div className="custom-tooltip" style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffff', padding: '5px', border: '1px solid #cccc' }}>
                <p>{`Expenditure on ${payload[0].name} : ${payload[0].value}K`}</p>
                <p>{'percentage: '+(`${payload[0].value}`*100/(sum_of_all_values)).toFixed(2)+'%'}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }     return null;
};
```

replace "(sum_of_all_values)" with actual sum of your values, or write another method which does the same and assign it's value in this place.